# VM & MS access - ExportWithFormatting PDF not working while in background

Tags: windows, ms-access, virtual-machine, export-to-pdf

I have a problem that i have a difficult time explaining, which makes any online search very hard. Here is my dilema.

I'm migrating a VM. The purpose of this machine is to compile send out daily/weekly/monthly reports. I know there are other ways (like Power BI) but this is the situation we are in right now. The older machine has win10 pro and office 365 installed while the new has win10 enterprise version and office 2016 installed. This machine runs 24/7 in the background running specific tasks (via system scheduler app) at given times, that is it's a Virtual machine and has done so without issues since it was created. The reason for the migration is because we need to domain change and bring the machine under a new corporate policy and we don't want to do this on a live server.

We've set it the VM's the same way, same programs and same settings. Everything seams to be running smooth expect for this one thing, **and here is the problem i have a hard time to explain or figure out:**

MS Access will update the tables and the computer will run the tasks as set but it will not export the data to pdf unless i have a remote desktop connection open. Will not export the pdf's otherwise. MS Access uses a autoexec macro where the pdf export is set with ExportWithFormatting. This works without issues on the old server.

We thought this to be a permission or user specific issue at first but even re-creating the tasks did not work and changing paths. Otherwise also i expect we would have problems with tables updating, specially since it works when you have an active remote desktop conn running.

I'm lost and therefore hoping this community will be able to help or guide me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we found the reason for this. It was caused by windows easy print and the printer drivers of the machine. It worked for some reason differently between the servers. after reinstalling the printer drivers and a few restarts it started working. It exports now from access again.

This is at least solved.